# Java layout ignored properties documentation

Tags: java, swing, layout

Is there a table documenting which properties each java layout ignores (max size, min size, etc)?

Comment: Is there a specific Layout Manager that you would like to know about?  Or, is there a certain effect you would like to accomplish?

Comment: @Justin'jjnguy'Nelson no, there isn't a specific layout manager. When working with swing gui I experience a lot of random problems becouse many layouts do not respect all the properties. E.g. when using box layout, and add a component to North, the component will not respect the maxHorizontalSize. And this is not described in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, `North` and `South` in `BorderLayout` will always take up the max horizontal size.  `East` and `West` will always take the full height.

Comment: @Justin'jjnguy'Nelson yes, and is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Most of the properties you are looking for are specified in the javadocs of the managers.  It may just be a little difficult to interpret what they mean all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of these properties are specified in the javadocs for the specific classes.  For example, [`BorderLayouts`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) behavior is specified as:

> The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The `NORTH` and `SOUTH` components may be stretched horizontally; the `EAST` and `WEST` components may be stretched vertically; the `CENTER` component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over.

And the [`FlowLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) specifies:

> A flow layout lets each component assume its natural (preferred) size.

The [`GridLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) specifies in the documentation for the constructor:

> All components in the layout are given equal size. [However large the grid is]

And [`BoxLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) states:

> BoxLayout attempts to arrange components at their preferred widths (for horizontal layout) or heights (for vertical layout). For a horizontal layout, if not all the components are the same height, BoxLayout attempts to make all the components as high as the highest component. If that's not possible for a particular component, then BoxLayout aligns that component vertically, according to the component's Y alignment. By default, a component has a Y alignment of 0.5, which means that the vertical center of the component should have the same Y coordinate as the vertical centers of other components with 0.5 Y alignment.
>
> Similarly, for a vertical layout, BoxLayout attempts to make all components in the column as wide as the widest component. If that fails, it aligns them horizontally according to their X alignments. For PAGE_AXIS layout, horizontal alignment is done based on the leading edge of the component. In other words, an X alignment value of 0.0 means the left edge of a component if the container's ComponentOrientation is left to right and it means the right edge of the component otherwise.

Comment: I would like if there's is a table summarizing this all, but looks like there isn't. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tom, it seems like the documentation is really spread out, kinda' sucks.